# where do the arguments go in this function?

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

I'm working through and trying to understand the source code of https://trianglify.io/ which can be found at https://github.com/qrohlf/trianglify. In the lib/trianglify.js file, I come across the following lines of code:

```
var x_color = chroma.scale(opts.x_colors).mode(opts.color_space);
var y_color = chroma.scale(opts.y_colors).mode(opts.color_space);
gradient = function(x, y) {
     return chroma.interpolate(x_color(x), y_color(y), 0.5, opts.color_space);
};
```

My question is when the x_color(x) gets called, where does the "x" argument go? How does this argument get passed into the function if it doesn't appear in the definition? My main purpose for doing this is to add some extra custom parameters to x_color() but I can't do that if I have no idea how the parameters even get processed in the function.

EDIT
The .mode(opts.color_space) function can be found at https://github.com/gka/chroma.js/blob/master/src/scale.coffee line 158. It reads as follows:

```
f.mode = (_m) ->
        if not arguments.length
            return _mode
        _mode = _m
        resetCache()
        f
```

not sure what to make of this since my coffeescript knowledge is limited.

Comment: Is the function not returned by `mode(opts.color_space)`? You need to show the `mode(...)` function definition in your question.

Comment: edited my post...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

chroma is part of `chroma.js`.

Looking at the code, `chroma.scale(...)` constructs a function with prototypes with [fluent methods](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface).

```
f = function(v) {
  var c;
  c = chroma(getColor(v));
  if (_out && c[_out]) {
    return c[_out]();
  } else {
    return c;
  }
};
f.mode = function(_m) {
  if (!arguments.length) {
    return _mode;
  }
  _mode = _m;
  resetCache();
  return f;
};
```

So when you call `chroma.scale(...)` it returns f, and then when you call `.mode(...)` on the returned object, it again returns the same instance f.

The instance of f is created by the following method:

```
chroma = function() {
    if (arguments[0] instanceof Color) {
      return arguments[0];
    }
    return (function(func, args, ctor) {
      ctor.prototype = func.prototype;
      var child = new ctor, result = func.apply(child, args);
      return Object(result) === result ? result : child;
    })(Color, arguments, function(){});
};
```

As you can see, this makes use of the [arguments](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments) object. Mozilla defines the arguments object as:

> The arguments object is an Array-like object corresponding to the arguments passed to a function.

In short, even if you do not specify parameter names in the function signature, the arguments object will still exist, and any parameters you pass will exist in the arguments array.

I've created an example of using the arguments array [here](https://jsfiddle.net/dfjajog4/8/)

```
function a() {
    alert(arguments[0] + ' is ' + arguments[1] + ' years old.');
}

function b(name) {
  return function test() {
      alert(name + ' will vw ' + arguments[0] + ' years old on his next birthday.');
  }
}

a('John', 29);
var example2 = b('John');
example2(30);
```

In the first example, there is a straight function call, but in the second example I am returning an actual function from the `b()` method, and then I'm calling that returned function.

Comment: Thanks that makes things clearer. How could I change things so that I could call x_color(x, opts.c_colors) so that opts.c_colors doesn't have to be global?

Comment: You could just call `chroma.scale(x_colors).mode(color_space)(color)` from within your gradient function.

Comment: while that works, it ends up running really slow because the gradient function runs in a for loop so I'm guessing some big object is being instantiated each call. Any way to call it with parameters while leaving chroma.scale outside of the gradient function?

Comment: You could pass the function returned by `chroma.scale(x_colors).mode(color_space);` into your gradient method: `gradient = function(x, y, x_color, y_color) {`